# Could we calculate pi using an iterative series

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

I know that, as a hobbyist mathematician, this is generally a term we can use to express pi

\begin{equation*} \frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13} - \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{17} - \cdots \end{equation*}

This is great representation , and  it works just fine

However, I've been introduced to some iterative series recently (they're great for finding the roots to an equation by the way) and I was wondering, if there was a iterative series for pi, could we get a more justified value?

I've looked online, and there only seems to be geometric expressions using sine and cosine.

I was wondering if a numerical formula could be derived.

Edit: An iterative series is a series much like an algorithm, for example (N+1) = root(N+ 2/N) the idea being this series will converge on a value

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'iterative series'? If I had to guess, I'd assume you meant using Newton's method to find the roots of a polynomial via iteration. To make your idea work, all you need do is find an equation with $\pi$ (or some rational multiple thereof) as one of its roots.

Comment: The fact that π is transcendental means that there is no polynomial (with rational coefficients) that has π as a root, so I'm not sure you'd find an iterative formula that's just a simple polynomial or rational function.

Comment: Iterative or recurrence? Leibniz formula for $\pi$ you stated, can be written as a recurrence $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$, $x_0=1$ by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are iterative *algorithms*. There are two beautiful ones by the [Borwein brothers](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~pborwein/PAPERS/P40.pdf), based on work by Ramanujan. Algorithm 1 involves the *[silver ratio](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SilverRatio.html)*, and Algorithm 2 involves the *cube* of the *[golden ratio](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html)*.

**I. Algorithm 1.** Start with seed values:

$$y_0 = -1+\sqrt{2}$$

$$a_0 = 2(-1+\sqrt{2})^2$$

and two iterative rules,

$$y_{n+1} = \frac{1-(1-{y_n}^4)^{1/4}}{1+(1-{y_n}^4)^{1/4}}\tag1$$

$$a_{n+1} = a_n(y_{n+1}+1)^4-2^{2n+3}\,y_{n+1}\big(y_{n+1}^2+y_{n+1}+1\big)\tag2$$

Then,

$$\quad\quad\quad\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = \pi\quad\text{(very fast)}$$

The difference grows *quartically*,

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\frac{1}{a_n} - \pi \approx 4^{n+2} q^{4^n},\quad \text{where}\;q = e^{-2\pi}$$

Thus for $n=1,2,3$, the difference is about $10^{-10},\,10^{-42},\,10^{-172},$ or more than the *fourth power* of the previous. It's that fast.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly it is that you want, but if you take newton's method and the power series of $\sin$ and $\cos$, you'll get $\pi$ as the limit of the newton iterations for $x_0 = 3$ and $x_{k+1} = x_k - \tan(x_k)$ where $\cot$ has a power series wich you can chose to evaluate up to an increasing degree, say $k$ to get
$$x_{k+1} = x_k - T_k[\tan](x_k)$$
Where $T_k[f]$ is the $k$-th sum of the Taylor series of $f$ at a predefined point near $\pi$ ($3$ for example). This will give you a new polynomial term each iteration but it forms a sequence with $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k = \pi$.

See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+tan%28x%29+near+x+%3D+pi) for $T_k[\tan]$

Comment: That taylor series looks scary.. I just saw a method online which was something like x + sin(x). That did the job just fine on my calculator.

Comment: @It'sRainingMen If that is allowed (using trigs), you could just use $x_{k+1} = x_k - \tan(x_k)$. I interpreted your question as to specifically ask to **avoid** trigonometric functions in the iteration.

Comment: Yes, the trigometric soloutions are less preferable since something like x + sin(x) is worthless when the calculator treats x as pi hence sin(x) as 0. Although that tan(x) sequence also works, i guess

Comment: You could also take $\tan(x) \approx \frac{T_k[\sin](x)}{T_k[\cos](x)}$ wich is a rational function and the series expansions are well known (Take a higher order to prevent moving out of the neighborhood of $\pi$ so you don't get a different root of $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The Basel infinite convergent serie (1/k squared) has the result of Pi squared over 6.By iterating actually you refine Pi value.There may be similar series that have a greater CONVERGING SPEED (you get PI decimals quicker).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one:

Consider a sequence where $S_1=0$, $S_2=1$,
and $S_{n+2}=\begin{cases}
      \frac{(Sn+S_{n+1})}{2}, & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
      \sqrt{Sn \cdot S_{n+1}}, & \text{if $n$ is even}
    \end{cases}$

Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \{\frac{2}{Sn}\}=\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a formula that I found that converges to pi squared. Here is a link related to that:

[A new formula for pi? If $A_1=4$ and $A_{n+1}=2^{2n+1}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{A_n}{2^{2n}}}\right)$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = \pi^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4847309/871083)