# A nice formula for pi

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

I would like to share a simple derivation of an iterative formula for Pi.

The formula I have derived:
$\begin{align}
A_1 &= 4 \\
A_{n+1} &=2*4^{n} \left(1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{A_n}{4^{n}}}\right). \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n &= \pi^2
\end{align}$

Note: After a bit of research I learned  that  formula  above is closely related to relations discovered a long time ago by Euler.

Despite the fact that such formula isn’t very special, I believe that together with the derivation below, it will provide a simple explanation for how Pi can be calculated using simple tools. (Without calculus for example)

Will be happy to hear feedback!

An informal derivation of the formula above:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That is rather...shall we say...rough and ready. By all means, add your proof and deriviation; but in Mathjax, not hand-written.

Comment: Noone can count how many formulas are known for $\pi$ , so it is not a good idea to publish a random new method even if it works. Only if you have found a very efficient way to calculate $\pi$ to many many digits , this might be worth to be published.

Comment: This is very cool!

Comment: Thank you all. I will shortly upload a derivation and try to compare its convergence to other formulas.

Comment: The solution of the recurrence relation above is $A_n=2^{2n}\cdot\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2^n}$. Hence the convergence of $A_n$ to $\pi^2$ for $n\to\infty$ is obvious.

Comment: $\sqrt{A_n}$ is essentially an application of half-angle formula of sine and evaluate $\pi$ as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$. This is similar to Archimedes' way of estimating $\pi$ by looking at perimeter of inscribed regular polygon in unit circle. Of course, Archimedes doesn't have the tool of square root. However, he bound the perimeter both from below and above by inscribed and circumscribed polygons. This is how he proved $\frac{223}{71} < \pi < \frac{22}{7}$.

Comment: Yes that is how I derived it. It is quite easy to proof that it converges to pi squared.  I just wander if there is anything innovative or useful about this formula.

Comment: Yea I used the sin of double angle formula. Not surprised that it been done like this before. Just wondered maybe not… 
Thanks for the feed back :)

Comment: @RotemTsafrir: *"Not surprised that it been done like this before."* That someone else got to this result before you is just —in the words of Stephen Fisk— "an accident of time". Keep in mind that there are a *lot* of smart and prolific people ahead of us on the timeline. (Euler, I'm looking at you ...) This doesn't diminish your accomplishment at having discovered something new for yourself. So, congratulations! and keep at it. After all, Euler didn't get around to *everything*.

Comment: So what is the question? This is reminiscent of Viete's pi formula.